# LDIF - Delete Attribute IF Exists

Tags: ldap, ldif

We are using the following LDIF to remove POSIX Attributes from our LDAP Directory. This works fine, except in the case where an attribute does not exist. For e.g. it will fail if the homedirectory attribute doesn't exist. How can I make this such that the rest of attributes will be deleted even if one or more of them are not set for an entry?

```
dn: uid=5,ou=people,o=company.com,o=corp
changetype: modify
delete: uidnumber
-
delete: homedirectory
-
delete: objectclass
objectclass: posixAccount
-
delete: loginshell
-
delete: unixusername
-
delete: gidnumber
-
```

Comment: Typically, ldif import utilities have an option for continue on error. Many use the -c option to specify that the tool should continue processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this sort of logic in the LDIF file itself. You'll have to separate out the modifications in different entries...

```
dn: uid=5,ou=people,o=company.com,o=corp
changetype: modify
delete: uidnumber

dn: uid=5,ou=people,o=company.com,o=corp
changetype: modify
delete: homeDirectory

dn: uid=5,ou=people,o=company.com,o=corp
changetype: modify
delete: loginShell
```

..and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an attribute to be replaced without providing a value will remove it if it doesn't exist:

```
dn: uid=5,ou=people,o=company.com,o=corp
changetype:modify
replace: title
title: Senior Developer
-
replace: departmentNumber
-
replace: displayName
displayName: Foo
```

This will delete the `departmentNumber` attribute.